# How transfer data from component to another component wia Subject/Observable?

Tags: angularjs

I find interesting example how transfer data from one component to another component using Subject/Observable in Service:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yMBoVkxohwhPig5COgkU?p=preview

I find it similar to broadcast event from Angular 1.X. But I notice that subscribe to data changes can only component that inishiated data change. I need somehow modify this example to get data in one component after another component changed it. Console.log dos't show any error, but data-transfer not working. Can anyone help?

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientsService {

    private _client$: Subject<Client>;
    private _clients$: Subject<Client[]>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this._client$ = <Subject<Client>>new Subject();
        this._clients$ = <Subject<Client[]>>new Subject();
    }

    getClients(): Promise<Client[]> {
        return this.http.get('api/Client')
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                this._clients$.next(res.json());
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    get client$() {
        return this._client$.asObservable();
    }

    get clients$() {
        return this._clients$.asObservable();
    }

    clientChangeBroadcast(objClient: Client) {
        this._client$.next(objClient);
    }

    clientsChangeBroadcast(arrClients: Client[]) {
        this._clients$.next(arrClients);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
```

First component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    clients: Client[];

    constructor(public clientsService: ClientsService) {
        this.clients = [];

    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    loadClients() {
        this.clientsService.getClients().then(clients => {
            this.clients = clients;
            this.clientsService.clientsChangeBroadcast(clients);
        });
    }

    selectClient(objClient: Client) {
        this.clientsService.getClients();
        this.clientsService.clientChangeBroadcast(objClient);
    }
}
```

Second component:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    client: Observable<Client>;
    clients: Observable<Client[]>;

    constructor(private clinetsService: ClientsService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

            //this.clinetsService.getClients();

            this.client = this.clinetsService.client$;
            this.clients = this.clinetsService.clients$;

            this.clinetsService.client$.subscribe(value => {
                // try to get changes here

            });

            this.clinetsService.clients$.subscribe(value => {
                // try to get changes here

            });
    }

    reLoadClients() {
        this.clinetsService.getClients();
    }

}
```

I try to get data changinf in 'Second component' after data was changed by 'First component'. When I click on button for 'selectClient' method in 'First component' I expect data transfer wia service and I catch changes ob 'Second component' -> it not working. When from 'Second component' I press button for 'reLoadClients' data transfer wia service and I catch changes in all subscribe functions on 'Second component'.

Comment: Good idea to link to running code, but you also need to include the snippet in the question. Because links eventually die, and then question becomes suddenly useless. And the point here is to have question that have a long lifespan. So please edit question, paste code (but keep the link!).

Comment: I add some code for details.